# EF Core 3.1 "Nullability in constraints for type parameter..." issue with interface and DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a .NET Core 3.1 assembly project using EF Core 3.1 that has nullable reference types turned on. I have created the following interface:

```cs
public interface IMyDbContext
{
      DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

I implement this interface in my context class:

```cs
public sealed class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
}
```

Since the DbContext base class already has a method with this signature I don't actually have to implement anything in the MyDbContext class.

I am getting the following warning:

> Nullability in constraints for type parameter 'TEntity' of method 'DbSet
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set()' doesn't match
>   the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method
>   'DbSet MyProject.IMyDbContext.Set()'. Consider using
>   an explicit interface implementation instead.

I confirmed this is caused by my project using nullable reference types and EF Core does not by removing the following from the project file:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Once I did that the warning went away.

I tried to change the interface as follows:

```cs
DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class?;
```

But no luck.

Is there a way to make this warning go away without removing nullable reference types from my project?

Comment: Does the error go away if you disable nullable reference types?

Comment: @devNull yes the error does go away if I remove nullable reference types. I will update the post to call that out.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. I tried setting to where TEntity : class? also, but did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met the same problem, solved it by overriding the Set method

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    { }

    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

The warning is gone, studio suggests that the method can be removed, but of course I will not do this =)

If there is another solution, I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

So I refuse to accept that the warning is even true because upon all investigation, it seems my IDbContext interface matches exactly how Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext implements the method.

So to deal with the warning's false positive nature, I have reluctantly changed my code to this as my "fix".

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext"/>
/// <inheritdoc cref="IDbContext"/>
#pragma warning disable 8633
public abstract partial class DbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, IDbContext
#pragma warning restore 8633
```